# Not able to delete a blob - GAE Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

With a proper Blob Key, I'm not able to delete a blob entry.. here is my code

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(thumbnailKey);
blobstoreService.delete(blobKey);
```

where, variable 'thumbnailKey' has a correct key...

i'm getting an exception as

```
com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreFailureException: An internal blobstore error occured.
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.delete(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:112)
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Is this still happening? If so can you attach more details from error?

Comment: Was this issued solved ?  I'd like to know what the issue was here.

Comment: Yes, The problem was with the GAE Version, I installed the latest version and it worked fine..

Answer (score 0):

As Amith said in the comments, the problem was with the version, and the solution is to upgrade to the latest version of Google App Engine.